# How to add a date column to a table with current date as default value?

Tags: sqlite

Where I can see which default columns SQLite table will have after creating?
I need a column with datetime which has default value of time when data added to the table.\

Now I'm trying:

```
ALTER TABLE recipes ADD COLUMN timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'));
```

And I'm obtaining the following message:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: ALTER TABLE recipes ADD COLUMN timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')); [ Cannot add a column with non-constant default ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
 Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)         [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` doesn't allow this: "The column may not have a default value of CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, or an expression in parentheses." https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the create table instead of altering the table. If there are values inside you'll have this kind of a problem. See

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-insert-timestamp-field-with-value-CURRENT-TIME-td42729.html

all the best

Comment: Ref link is broken

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200206070252/http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-insert-timestamp-field-with-value-CURRENT-TIME-td42729.html